# PHP ldap bind issue

Tags: php, ldap, ldapconnection

I've been looking at a couple of guides (and the PHP manual) trying to validate AD users on an intranet site I'm about to make. This is the first time I've used ldap_connect, and I haven't had the best of luck.

Could anyone look at my code and see what I'm missing?

Thanks.

```
<?php
    $user = "08jf1";
    $password = "pass";

    // Active Directory server
    $ldap_host = "10.43.48.5"; 

    // Active Directory DN
    $ldap_dn = "OU=CSE-W7,OU=Students-W7,DC=server,DC=local";

    // Domain, for purposes of constructing $user
    $ldap_usr_domain = "@server.local";

    // Connect to AD host
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect("10.43.48.5");

    if ($ldapconn) { 
            $bind = ldap_bind($ldap_host, $ldap_dn, $user . $ldap_usr_domain, $password);

            if ($bind) {
                echo "Verified user";

                //$_SESSION['username'] = $session_username;
                //$_SESSION['password'] = $session_password;

                } else {
                    echo "User does not exist";
                }
        }
?>
```

**Edit:** I can confirm ldap is enabled though phpinfo!

Answer (score 2):

Is that syntax of `ldap_bind` correct?. Isn't it `ldap_bind($ldapconn,$rdn,$password)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Binding may need a elevated privilege or authbind wrapper. Refer to authbind for ldap. [LDAP AuthBind](http://wiki.dovecot.org/AuthDatabase/LDAP/AuthBinds)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this very simple example: [How to use LDAP Active Directory Authentication with PHP](http://www.exchangecore.com/blog/how-use-ldap-active-directory-authentication-php/)